# Writing a function to find a root using secant method in R

Tags: r, while-loop, numerical-methods, newtons-method

The tag of Newton-Raphson Method is incorrect, I'm actually using the Secant method; but I do not have the reputation to create a new tag.

I think I am not too far off. I have a function that I've named `ISO()` to compute fluid dynamics. It is non-linear so to find the root of the equation I need to solve it numerically. I have chosen to use the Secant Method as I believe it to be the simplest method for what I would like to do.

Where I think I am having issues is with the reassigning of the the initial "guesses" that I use to begin the iteration. I am using a while loop, and I am counting the number of iterations.

```
sec <- function(x){

  Number_Of_Iterations = 0 # Starts the counter

  x1 = x
  x2 = 3*x

  while(x2 - x1 > 0.0001){ # This is how I'm trying to converge the points.

    Number_Of_Iterations = Number_Of_Iterations + 1

    # The secant function to determine a new x:

    x_new = x2 - ISO(x1)*(x2 - x1)/(ISO(x2) - ISO(x1))

    if(x2 - x_new > x_new - x1){ # These were the rules that I set to reassign the inital chosen values.

      x2 = x_new
      x1 = x1

    }else{

      x1 = x_new
      x2 = x2

    }

  }
  m_dot = x_new
  m_dot

}
```

When I run this code, I get the number of iterations is 1, and a value for `m_dot` to equal a value different to what is achieved when calculating the first iteration by hand. I have checked, my `ISO()` function returns the same value as when I calculate it by hand, so the underlying functions do work, I just don't think I can get my `sec()` function to coverage with what I have written.

All assistance greatly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly are the values of `x1, x2, x_new, ISO(x1), ISO(x2)` at the last iteration? This or a more complete debug output would help to find the source of the problem in this non-standard variant of the not-secant, not-regula-falsi method.

Comment: Why don't you use the `secant` function from package `pracma`? Works perfectly.

Comment: Your test should be with the absolute value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately my issue wasn't just a coding problem; it was problem when using the Secant Method. My initial estimates to begin the iterations made the function analyse an incorrect range.

The advice given by LutzL went a very long way to answering my question, `abs()` was necessary, and his(or her) suggestion of taking the functions out of the secant formula will probably use a lot less computing power.

Here's my working code:

```
sec <- function(x){

  x1 = x
  x2 = x/10 # I have changed the initial values so that x1 is the larger of the two initial estimates.

  while(abs(x2 - x1) > 0.0000001){ # This is how I'm trying to converge the points.

    # The secant function to determine a new x:

    x_new = x2 - square(x2)*(x2 - x1)/(square(x2) - square(x1))

    # I have changed from ISO(), to a simple quadratic formula, I named square(). This secant function works for all of
    # the functions I have since tested it on.

    if( abs(x2 - x_new) > abs(x_new - x1)){

      x2 = x_new

    }else{

      x1 = x_new

    }

  }

  m_dot = x_new
  m_dot

}
```

The reason I chose to write my own secant formula instead of using an inbuilt function from a package was because this function is very simple to create, and I think it's more rewarding to use my own code other than relying on packages written by others.

I hope this helps others who are new to coding, and many thanks to those who provided answers, especially to LutzL, as without their suggestions, I do not think I would have been able to solve this as quickly as I did.

Answer (score 0):

I can guess what happened: The function values at the initial points have the same sign, so that the secant root `x_new` is outside the interval `[x1, x2]`. Then by the re-assignment logic you get that in the next iteration `x2<x1` so that in the test for the interval length the difference `x2-x1` is negative and thus smaller than the positive threshold. Thus exit after one iteration with no root found.

The most probable intent was that all the comparisons were for length, that is the absolute value of the differences. Thus change to

```
 while( abs(x2 - x1) > 0.0001){ # This is how I'm trying to converge the points.
    ...
    if( abs(x2 - x_new) > abs(x_new - x1) ){ # These were the rules that I set to reassign the inital chosen values.
```

---

Btw.: By your description, the function ISO seems to be costly. Store the values of their evaluation once and reuse these values wherever needed, mainly in

```
x_new = x2 - y2*(x2 - x1)/(y2 - y1)
```

(Note that I corrected the typo from y1 to y2, you are solving the equality of slopes `(x2-x_new)/(y2-0) = (x2 - x1)/(y2 - y1)` to find the secant root.)

Thus set `y1=ISO(x1); y2=ISO(x2);` at the start and inside the loop add to the re-assignment of the `x` values the computation of the `y` value.

```
   x2 = x_new; y2 = ISO(x_new);
```

respective

```
   x1 = x_new; y1 = ISO(x_new);
```

This way for any of the `x` values used the ISO function is evaluated exactly once.